# What does rel="search" do?

Tags: html, meta

In the `head` of Stack Overflow there is this tag:

```
 <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
```

I'm wondering what it does and if it's related to SEO?

I could find this quote:

> Provides a link to a resource that can be used to search through the current document and its related pages.

This is a bit cryptic. Who is searching? Blind people? Google Bots?

Here is the content of the file:

```
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
<ShortName>Stack Overflow</ShortName>
<Description>
Search Stack Overflow: Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers
</Description>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
<Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d
</Image>
<Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

And here is the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSearch) page on opensearch which states:

> OpenSearch is a collection of technologies that allow publishing of
>   search results in a format suitable for syndication and aggregation.
>   It is a way for websites and search engines to publish search results
>   in a standard and accessible format. OpenSearch was developed by
>   Amazon.com subsidiary A9 and the first version, OpenSearch 1.0, was
>   unveiled by Jeff Bezos at the O'Reilly Emerging Technology Conference
>   in March, 2005. Draft versions of OpenSearch 1.1 were released during
>   September and December 2005. The OpenSearch specification is licensed
>   by A9 under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 2.5 License.

This is still too cryptic for me.

Comment: It is used to Add the autoDiscovery Link you can find more here :http://blog.unto.net/add-opensearch-to-your-site-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: check this developer mozilla  doc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/OpenSearch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**About the search Value**
The search value of the rel attribute gives a link to a resource that can be used to search through the current document and its related pages.

**About the rel Attribute**
The rel attribute specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document. Only used if the href attribute is present.

This link says it all.
http://www.stateofdigital.com/good-rel-attributes-beginners-guide/